# ASP.Net Dynamic popup window

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have a C# web app that pulls a json object from a web service after a button click even. This object has HTML code saved in one of its properties. I need to popup a window to the user from this server side event that displays this HTML.

The event could also return a list of objects so I would need the ability to display the popups one after the other.

What is the best way this handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was lookinf for here

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/javascript-dynamic-document-creation-in-new-windows.html